# Библиотека классов. Как определить платформы?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-core, библиотеки

Я хочу сделать библиотеку классов (DLL) для упрощенной работы с базовыми типами данных, с новыми методами расширения и т.д. То есть, это не что-то такое, что должно работать только в WinForms или Xamarin, но я не понимаю, как такую библиотеку написать. Если это будет .NET Framework, то я не смогу использовать ее в Core, если будет Core - наоборот. Как-то пробовал писать под .NET Standard, но не смог потом ее подключить под фреймворк. Неужели, мне нужно будет дублировать код, чтобы собирать под разные платформы? Ведь сам код будет **абсолютно идентичным**.

Comment: Забудьте про .NET Framework, он уже умер. .NET Standard тоже уходит в небытие. [The future of .NET Standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/). Создавайте свою библиотеку на .NET 6 (это LTS-версия).

Comment: Об этом не подумал. Единственное, мне бывает самому необходимо сделать форму с парой кнопок или еще чего-то для какой-то задачи, и хотелось бы использовать такие библиотеки свои, как тогда быть?

Comment: Ничто не мешает создавать проект WinForms под современный .NET 6 и выше.

Comment: Прочитал, есть WF не под фреймворк. Спасибо!